# spark delta lake on s3 (jvm)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, jvm, delta-lake

I'm working with `spark 3.3.0` and `delta 2.1.0 - scala version 2.12` on `kotlin`. I am trying to write a delta `database.table` to s3 while preserving the same layout as it would on my local drive.

**code**

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("deltaTestApp")
    //  Delta Connectivity
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    // AWS Connectivity
    .config("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .config("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
    .config("fs.s3a.access.key", System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_ID"))
    .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", System.getenv("AWS_SECRET"))
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .orCreate;

val myData = fetchData()
val df = spark.createDataFrame(myData, MyDataClass::class.java)

// Output of df createDataFrame()
+------+--------------------+---------+
|   C1 |              C2    |     C3  |
+------+--------------------+---------+
|   A1 |             AA     |     01  |
|   B2 |             BB     |     02  |
|   C3 |             CC     |     03  |
|   D4 |             DD     |     04  |
|   E5 |             EE     |     05  |
+------+--------------------+---------+
```

I then proceed to save it as a delta file locally as a test.

```
spark.sql("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST2;")
df.write().format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("TEST2.sec")
```

This is how it looks like after the writing happens.

[image: local saving image]

This output is precisely what I am hoping to achieve on `s3` storage, where there is a `schema.db`/`tableName` layout.

I can then proceed to do various things like `spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED test2.sec ;").show()` and it'll print out the table details for me.

And `spark.read().format("delta").load("spark-warehouse/test2.db/sec").show()` to show the details of the table.

**My problem**

when I try to migrate it over to `s3` with the modification: `spark.sql("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST2 LOCATION 's3a://path/to/spark-warehouse';")`

The layout does not appear like the screenshot above. (It shows no changes). When I add the `df.write().format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("path", "s3a://path/to/spark-warehouse").saveAsTable("TEST2.sec")`, it shows up like this instead: [image]

Any idea why this is different? FYI - I am also unable to do `spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED test2.sec ;").show()` for the `s3` `database.tableName` object as well.

Comment: I think its because its `UNMANAGED`.. so, have to set up my own hive metastore and connect to it and make it a managed table to achieve the same thing. but its just my guess. if anyone can confirm it, it'll be great. :)

Comment: `val path = "s3a://data/processed/my_data"`  `dfToWrite.write.format("delta").save(path)` this will create `my_data` as delta table at `path`. Try with `save()` .

Comment: What Spark runtime are you using?  Can you add that to the question?